# Generating model coefficient matrix of variable sizes during Cross validation

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to prepare a proper structure(e.g. matrix or data frame) for storing the results of a cross validation process for linear regression. As part of that, I need to store the error matrix for each run and each selection of prediction coefficients. Since the number of coefficients depends on number of features, the entries in the matrix/dataframe will be variable. What is the best approach for storing them?
I thought of separating error matrix and prediction-Coefficient matrix, but not able to proceed on the prediction-Coefficient part because the size of the entries are variable. 
As a trial example, this is what I tried proceeding the structure as a matrix.

Q1. Is it possible to have a structure to store the coefficient vectors into matrix or dataframe in such a way that we can access it to select the one with smallest error?
Q2. What is a good approach for this problem?

```
> a1 <- matrix(1:2, nrow=2, ncol=1)
> a2 <- matrix(2:3, nrow=2, ncol=1)
> b1 <- matrix(1:3, nrow=3, ncol=1)
> b2 <- matrix(2:4, nrow=3, ncol=1)
> 
> a1
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
> a2
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
> b1
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
> b2
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4
> M <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=2, ncol=2)
> M[1,1] <- a1
Error in M[1, 1] <- a1 :
```

### number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Here is what I am referring to replies:

```
> j <- list(first=a2, second=b2)
> k <- list(first=a1, second=b1)
> j
$first
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3

$second
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4

> k
$first
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

$second
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3

> M <- list(A=k, B=j)
> M
$A
$A$first
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

$A$second
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3


$B
$B$first
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3

$B$second
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4
```

I modified the above code a little bit so that I can use LETTERS and letters as below:

```
> j <- list(a=a1, b=b1)
> k <- list(a=a2, b=b2)
> M <- list(A=j, B=k)
> M
$A
$A$a
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

$A$b
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3


$B
$B$a
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3

$B$b
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    4
```

I hope I can ask as follow up question in this discussion itself as it is relevant for the same topic. Suppose, from the error matrix, minimum is having index [1, 1] (i.e. row=1 and column =1), then correspondingly I have to access the list element M$A$a (from the above code). So I tried the below code:

```
> m <- LETTERS[1]
> n <- letters[1]
> t <- noquote(paste0("M", "$", m, "$", n, sep=""))
> t
[1] M$A$a
> t <- as.expression(t)
> t
expression("M$A$a")
> eval.parent(t, n=1)
[1] "M$A$a"
```

So, I can not get the M$A$a in this way, but if I execute the below code, I get the required list element:

```
> eval.parent(M$A$a, n=1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: It's not very clear, but you could try using a `list` maybe.

Comment: If you use a list but give the prediction-error statistic the same name in each list item, you should be able to store all the results in one object (list) but still write functions that identify or select one of those items from a comparison of those statistics.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: The idea I am following is to create two matrices: one for the error and the other for the prediction Coefficient. I can find the minimum for each model class and then use the index for accessing the corresponding prediction coefficients.

Comment: @ulfelder: If I understood correctly, you are suggesting to create the list of pairs for each error and corresponding coefficients but the problem we face is to move from one element of the list to other in the process of finding minimum. I tried the following updates in my first question but it seems I have more processing to access the corresponding prediction coefficient matrix.